# Why can't I get the square root of this symmetric positive-definite matrix in armadillo?

Tags: c++, armadillo

I have the matrix A:

0 0 0 0 1 1

0 0 0 0 0 1

0 0 0 0 0 1

0 0 0 0 0 1

1 0 0 0 0 0

1 1 1 1 0 0.

---

This matrix is clearly symmetric, so A*A is clearly a positive-definite matrix. I tried to calculate its square root in armadillo but failed. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace arma;
using namespace std;

int main(){
    mat A(6,6);
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){ // this part just reads the matrix,
        for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
            int x;
            scanf("%d",&x);
            A(i,j)=x;
        }
    }
    cout << sqrtmat_sympd(A*A);
}
```

I compiled it, and it works for some matrices like the identity matrix, but when I try with this one it says:

```
error: sqrtmat_sympd(): transformation failed
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  sqrtmat_sympd(): transformation failed
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Your matrix is not positive definite. It is positive semi definite which has 0 eigenvalue.

Comment: ok you are right, but it seems tu work with some other positive semi-definite matrices. I mean, clearly it has a square root right?

Comment: The matrix `A` is singular (e.g. two rows the same, two columns the same), so `A*A` is actually positive-indefinite or positive semi-definite (depending on jargon you use).   Theoretically, not all such matrices have a square root (particularly one with real elements) and attempting to calculate such a thing numerically is problematical (e.g. division by zero).

Comment: I guess, but isn't that sort of dumb? I mean clearly such matrices also have a square root. It works on on other matrices (like the zero matrix).

Comment: The zero matrix has a square root with real elements, even though it is singular.   Try to calculate its inverse, however, and you'll have trouble.

Comment: @peter what do you mean? every such matrix has a square root. Just diagonalize it, if you get DBD^{-1} then the matrix D\sqrt{B}D^{-1} is the one you want.

Comment: @Peter well yeah, if its singular it wont be invertible, but symmetric positive semi-definite matrices always have square root with non-negative eigenvalues.

Comment: Consider what happens if diagonalising results in a row or column that is all zeros.

Comment: it won't matter, you can still take the matrix B\sqrt{D} B^{-1}. Look here, it says a positive semi-definite matrix has a unique positive semi-definite square root. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why it works for some definite semi-positive matrices and not for others seems to be that sometimes the eigenvalues that are supposed to be zero turn out to be negative numbers with small norm. This causes a problem since the algorithm most likely takes the square roots of the eigenvalues somewhere down the road.

To be able to get the square root of a symmetric definite semi-positive symmetric matrix we can use the eigenvalue decomposition feature, and then take the square root of the diagonal part.(being careful to change the "negative zeros" to actual zeros.

Here is some code that does this:

```
mat raiz(const mat& A){
  vec D;
  mat B;
  eig_sym(D,B,A);

  unsigned int n = D.n_elem;

  mat G(n,n,fill::zeros);

  for(unsigned int i=0;i<n;i++){
      if(D(i)<0 ) D(i)=0;
      G(i,i)=sqrt(D(i));
  }

  return B*G*B.t();
}
```

**NOTE**: the [sqrtmat()](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#sqrtmat) function might be more appropriate, as it already attempts approximate matrix square root.

Comment: The only reason I am uploading this is It might help others having the same problem. I already solved the problem on my own.

Comment: The code still has basic bugs in it. (1) matrix G is not set to zeros before use and only the diagonal of matrix G is set; the off-diagonal elements of G are garbage, leading to the wrong result being returned; read the documentation on the [mat class](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#Mat) to see how to initialize matriices correctly. (2) matrix A is needlessly copied on entry to raiz(), causing extra memory use and slowdowns; use a const reference instead. (3) There is no need to take the inverse of transpose of matrix B; it's faster and simpler to use B\*G\*B.t()

Comment: @mtall thanks for the response, I think I have managed to solve two of the bugs, but I don't know how to use a const reference, would you mind editing that part?

Comment: I've modified the code. However, it would still be better to use the more general [`sqrtmat()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#sqrtmat) instead of the specialized [`sqrtmat_sympd()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#sqrtmat\_sympd) or your `raiz()` function. [`sqrtmat()`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#sqrtmat)  will try to work out approximate matrix square root. Example: `cx_mat B = sqrtmat(A);`

Comment: @mtall the problem with sqrtmat is that it doesn't always give you the principal square root.